# Rails: Twilio::REST::RestError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have added the `twilio gem`to my app in order to verify phone numbers. And this is the setup I have:

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_client, only: [:create, :verify]
  before_action :current_user, only: [:verify]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    channel = user_params['channel']
    @user = User.new(user_params.except('channel', 'displayed_phone_number'))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        start_verification(@user.phone_number, channel)
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        format.html { redirect_to verify_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def verify
    if request.post?
      is_verified = check_verification(@current_user.phone_number, params['verification_code'])
      if is_verified
        @current_user.verified = true
        @current_user.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to main_index_url, notice: 'User was successfully verified.' }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to verify_url, notice: 'The code was invalid.' }
        end
      end
    else
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_client
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone_number)
    end

    def start_verification(to, channel='sms')
      channel = 'sms' unless ['sms', 'voice'].include? channel
      verification = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID'])
                                   .verifications
                                   .create(:to => to, :channel => channel)
      return verification.sid
    end

    def check_verification(phone, code)
      verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID'])
                                         .verification_checks
                                         .create(:to => phone, :code => code)
      return verification_check.status == 'approved'
    end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :username %>
    <%= form.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :displayed_phone_number %>
    <%= form.text_field :displayed_phone_number, type: 'tel' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="channel">Verification Method</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="channel" value="sms" checked>SMS</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="channel" value="voice">Call</label>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Sign Up' %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("#user_displayed_phone_number");
  window.intlTelInput(input, {
    hiddenInput: "phone_number",
    preferredCountries: ["us", "gb", "co", "de"]
  });
</script>
```

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :phone_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Veirfy form:

```
<% title 'Verify' %>

<header><h1>Verify</h1></header>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_tag(verify_url) do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :verification_code %>
    <%= text_field_tag :verification_code %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Verify' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'main/index'

  resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index, :destroy]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  get 'verify', to: 'users#verify', as: 'verify'
  post 'verify', to: 'users#verify'
  get 'register', to: 'users#new', as: 'register'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  root 'main#index'
end
```

When I test this, I receive the phone call or the sms with the verification code. I enter it inside the the verfication form and all works just fine, the phone number gets verified. But when I enter a wrong code or not a code at all... instead of getting the notice message `The code was invalid.` I get this error:

```
Twilio::REST::RestError in UsersController#verify
[HTTP 400] 60200 : Unable to create record Invalid parameter: Code https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200
```

Which is from the users controller and this method:

```
def check_verification(phone, code)
  verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID']).verification_checks.create(:to => phone, :code => code)
  return verification_check.status == 'approved'
end
```

And the error is at this line:

```
verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID']).verification_checks.create(:to => phone, :code => code)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That error message says that the code parameter is invalid. I would assume you'd get that in the case of not sending a code. So I would probably build into your `check_verification` method an early return if the code is blank (it's not going to be correct anyway).

```rb
    def check_verification(phone, code)
      return false if code.blank?
      verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID'])
                                         .verification_checks
                                         .create(:to => phone, :code => code)
      return verification_check.status == 'approved'
    end
```

As for submitting the wrong code, do you get the same error raised and same message?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @philnash. I added your code and when the code is blank the error doesn't appear but when the code is wrong i get this: `[HTTP 404] 20404 : Unable to create record The requested resource /Services/VA3bdd17cd7687a1f9221ec0e243440eca/VerificationCheck was not found https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404`

Comment: So basically what I'm trying to implement is: When the code is empty or invalid a flash message should appear stating that the code is not valid. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: This is weird, I cannot reproduce that behaviour. You're getting what's effectively a Twilio 404 (we call it 20404) meaning something couldn't be found. I've tried using the verification service and verifying with the wrong code and I get a result with a status of "pending" which is expected. Do you have the latest version of the `twilio-ruby` gem?

Comment: I know, it's really weird! Yes I'm using `twilio-ruby 5.31.3`. Any ideas how to bypass /troubleshoot this error and also add the flash messages as I described above?

Comment: A workaround would be to `rescue` from that error and return false instead. But it would be best to get to the bottom of it. Is there something different about how the phone number is stored on the `@current_user` compared to how it's entered initially? Are you definitely sending the number in international (e164) format both times?

Comment: Well I have two different fields in the database when the phone is stored. A country code field and a phone field, but then I combine them like this:    `@phone_number = @current_user.phone_number.country_code + @current_user.phone_number.phone` and this is the output i get: +15108675310

Comment: In the code you call on `@current_user.phone_number`. And your model says there is a `phone_number` field that you validate. So that doesn't sound like the same treatment there. It still might not be the problem though. What happens if you perform a verification outside of these controllers, just by calling the methods in `irb`?

Comment: I'm sorry ignore the above, i just do this `@current_user.phone_number`

Comment: When I enter this in the irb: `@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])`  and then this `verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID']).verification_checks.create(:to => "+13023694209", :code => "")`

Comment: I get this: `Twilio::REST::RestError ([HTTP 400] 60200 : Unable to createrecord) Invalidparameter: Code https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200`

Comment: And when I enter this in the irb: `@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])`  and then this `verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID']).verification_checks.create(:to => "+13023694209", :code => "1234567890")`

Comment: I get this: `Twilio::REST::RestError ([HTTP 404] 20404 : Unable to create record)
The requested resource /Services/VA3bdd17cd7687a1f9221ec0e243440eca/VerificationCheck was not found https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404`

Comment: It's really weird, right? Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Been exploring this more. [Twilio deletes the verification after it expires or the max number of attempts to verify it are passed](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check#check-a-verification). Once it is deleted, you will receive the 20404 error. Is it possible that your verifications have timed out or passed the max number of attempts?

Comment: Thanks for your time and help @philnash. I just went with the following and no errors appear now. But is it the correct approach though? `begin
      verification_check = @client.verify.services(ENV['VERIFICATION_SID']).verification_checks.create(:to => phone, :code => code)
      return verification_check.status == 'approved'
    rescue Twilio::REST::RestError => error
      @error = error
      return false
    end`

Comment: I think that is the best approach for now and I can only apologise that it's not what is advertised. The team is working to identify and fix this problem. I might suggest you check the error's code and if you receive a 20404 then you know it's an incorrect code, but if it's something else you might want to re-raise as it's an issue elsewhere that you don't want to ignore. Other than that, that should work for you.